# dotnet 8 blazor server file upload and save not working

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I was writing some stuff to learn blazor but looks like file upload is not working as I expected so I created a new solution with the standard blazor server example and I replaced the counter page with this to create a simplified example of what I am doing:

```
@page "/counter"
<InputFile multiple OnChange="OnChange" class="form-control"></InputFile>

@code {
private async Task OnChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e) {



    foreach (var item in e.GetMultipleFiles()) {

        var buffer = new byte[item.Size];

        var readstream = item.OpenReadStream(item.Size);
        await readstream.ReadAsync(buffer.AsMemory(0, (int) item.Size));

        var f = File.Create(@"C:\test\image.jpg", buffer.Length, FileOptions.None);

        await f.WriteAsync(buffer);


        await f.FlushAsync();
        f.Dispose();
        readstream.Dispose();

    }
}
```

}

and it still doesn't work. If I upload an image it should save it to the file, and it does, but if I try with a 1 MB image the saved image is kind of weird, like if it has some messed up bytes or the file is not complete. Why?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using blazor 8 and that the same thing happens if I save the image in my DB with ef

Comment: Have you read this yet? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: yes, am I missing something? `   FileStream fs = new($@"C:\test\{Guid.NewGuid()}.jpg", FileMode.Create);
   await item.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(fs);
   fs.Dispose();` works even worse because it creates a 0 bytes file (sorry for bad formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this. Its already very Similar to your current code. For clarification loadedFiles is just a List with the items/Images that were put into the InputFile element. I picked loadedFiles[0] just for simplicity. Hope this helps

```
private async Task ShowCase()
{
    
    IBrowserFile fi = loadedFiles[0]; //this is just specific to a testcase. For you this is your item
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    await fi.OpenReadStream(fi.Size).CopyToAsync(stream);
    byte[] imageBytes = stream.ToArray();

    await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(@$"C:\Your\Path\{fi.Name}", imageBytes);

}
```

Comment: this works but I still not understand why my code does not. Absolutely crazy. Thanks!

Comment: The result of OpenReadStream should be guarded in a using statement

Answer (score 2):

Arriving late, but with some ideas.
Sometimes, you cant write directly in the "c:/" path, and it is necessary to get elevated permission (run app as admin). If you change your path to a user folder, it wouldn't be a problem.

Another problem is, sometimes if the file is very large, it can't be read using a single call to the ReadASync method, and you need to use a loop to read small parts.

Finally, I don't recommend using a byte buffer if you are not going to transform that element into memory. Just write directly to the file itself and avoid wasting memory.

As an extra, I share my code for this problem:

```
<InputFile id="@ImageId" OnChange="OnImageSelected" accept="image/jpg" />

@code {
  private async Task OnChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs fileargs)
  {
      IBrowserFile selectedImage = fileargs.File;
      string imageName = selectedImage.Name;

      using Stream stream = fileargs.File.OpenReadStream(fileargs.File.Size);

      using var f = File.Create($"C:\{imageName}.jpg", (int) stream.Length, FileOptions.None);

      await stream.CopyToAsync(f);
  }
}
```

For multiple files instead of one, the implementation doesn't vary much.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the server is configured to handle larger file uploads

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services. Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 104857600;
    });
}
```

Use the CopyToAsync method to copy the stream

```
private async Task OnChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in e.GetMultipleFiles())
    {
        var buffer = new byte[item.Size];
        var readStream = item.OpenReadStream(item. Size);
        using (var fileStream = File.Create(@"C:\test\image.jpg"))
        {
            await readStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```